# How can I avoid that the taskbar buttons get combined for my application when the user opens it twice?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

In more recent versions of Windows the taskbar will combine two buttons together when I open the same application twice. What can I do to avoid that (not counting changing the Windows settings, because I want it for my application only, not all applications).

Comment: Do you want to limit to only one instance of your application or do you prefer multiple?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120820-00/?p=6813/

Comment: @RossBush I need multiple but not grouped together, for easy switching between multiple instances.

Comment: @Joey Thanks, this is exactly what I need. I've implemented it and it works. You should post it as an answer so I can mark it.

Comment: @viking_grll: Iwas on the phone, so writing an actual answer with crucial information duplicated from the linked page was a bit too cumbersome. Rectified now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raymond Chen has detailed how to do this a while ago on his blog: [How do I customize how my application windows are grouped in the Taskbar?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120820-00/?p=6813/):

> All the information in this article came from the article [Application User Model IDs (AppUserModelIDs)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378459(v=VS.85).aspx) in MSDN.
>
> Okay, so suppose your application is really a runtime for other applications. What you need to do is assign a different AppID to each of the applications you are hosting. The mechanism for this is up to you. Your applications might explicitly provide a unique ID, or you may be able to infer one. For example, if you are Internet Explorer and your "applications" are pinned Web sites, you can use the URL of the site being pinned as the unique ID.
>
> You then get to take your unique IDs and create AppIDs for them. The [format of an AppID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378459(v=VS.85).aspx#how) is
>
> ```
> CompanyName.ProductName.SubProduct.VersionInformation
> ```
>
> where the Sub­Product is optional, and the Version­Information is present only if you want different versions of your app to be treated as distinct. (If you want an upgraded version to be a replacement for the old version, then omit the Version­Information so that the old and new versions use the same AppID.)
>
> You then assign this AppID to every window associated with the "application". You can do this for an entire process by calling `SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID`, or you can do it on a [window-by-window basis](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/06/01/10170113.aspx) by setting the `PKEY_AppUserModel_ID` property.